# How to show images on Google Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I create a Google Extension just like Google Translator Extension. After I upload my extension to Google, it doesn't show image when I select a word. It works on my local well, but on server I see this message on console [image] . Is there a way to fix this issue?

I use React.js and Material UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest.json

Add this line

```
"web_accessible_resources": [{ "resources": ["your_image_path"], "matches": ["<all_urls>"] }],
```

then use this image by doing this:

```
const imageUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL("your_image_path");
imageElement.src = imageUrl;
```

Comment: Hey thank you, I didn't understand the 2nd part. When I add chrome.runtime... , I get Cannot find name 'chrome'.ts(2304) error. And where does imageElement comes? Can you please explain?

Comment: First add this line in your tsconfig.json
`"typeAcquisition": { "include": ["chrome"] }`.
then read more at chrome docs : [method-getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL).
imageElement is your any html element. replace this with own element.

Comment: Worked thank you. In addition, if you want to include chrome to your tsconfig.json, you need to install this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome as well. Before I install this package, I was still getting TS error.